# Why is this returning zero in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, printf

When I run the result is zero, except for `-5`. I checked, it has nothing to do with the last line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int x;
    float E;
    cin >> x;
    if((float)x!=-5)
    {
        E=(x+3)/(x+5);
        cout << "Valoarea expresiesi este: " << E;
    }
    else 
        cout << "You cannot divide by zero";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

What did I miss? Thank you.

Comment: Look up *integer division*. You are dividint two ints. If the magnitude of the denominator is larger than that of the numerator you get `0`. There are SO duplicates around.

Comment: This doesn't always return `0`. Try feeding this `-6`.

Comment: [Another duplicate on integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

`(x+3)/(x+5)` is evaluated as an integer division, which rounds toward zero. It doesn't matter that `E` is a float, because neither `x+3` nor `x+5` is a float. As you've written it, the conversion to floating-point will happen after the rounding has already occurred. Convert an operand to floating-point *before* performing the operation:

```
E = (1.0*x+3) / (x+5);
```

Comment: And how can I specify the number of decimal places? f2.22E doesn't work.

Comment: @Tamás: I have no idea what `f2.22E` is supposed to be. In C, we'd use `printf` with a format specifier indicating 2 decimal places. I dunno about C++.

Comment: OK. I'm in college and they are supposed to be teaching me c++ and we used the above format specifier along with printf

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing two integers and the result will be zero since the denominator is larger.  To simply solve this, use 3.0 and 5.0 as your literals.

```
E = (x + 3.0) / (x + 5.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

For any `x > -5`, `(x+3)/(x+5)`, the denominator will always be greater than numerator and the integer division will always return 0. Only if you provide `x < -5` the answer will never be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever compare floats/doubles with strict comparisson `==` nor `!=`. What you should do is

```
if ( fabs(x-5) < 0.00001 ) { // logically x == 5
}
else {
}
```

**EDIT**

Check also my post about [infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240634/190281)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, `x` is an integer, so using a tolerance for the comparison is pointless.

Comment: I know but it looks like he's beginning his journey with C++ so I wanted him to know about floating point numbers comparison.